# Google Calendar event from responses color

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got a script working which takes a Google Forms response and creates an event based on the submission for a school where teachers can book rooms and equipment.
I would like to add these new events to an existing calendar where there are already some events manually added with a different color. For example the calendar's main color is red but I want the events from the form to be shown as blue.

Because I have not learned Javascript, I cannot find out **where** to insert **which type** of code that specifies the color of the newly added event.

```
var GLOBAL = {
  //the id of the form we will use to create calendar events 
  formId : "xxx",  
  
  //the id of the calendar we will create events on
  calendarId : "xxx",
  
  //a mapping of form item titles to sections of the calendar event
  formMap : {
    eventTitle: "Mille võtad",
    startTime : "Millal võtad",
    endTime: "Mis ajal tagastad",
    description: "Märkused, lisainfo",
    location: "Asutus",
    email: "Kes võtab",
  },
}

function onFormSubmit() {
  var eventObject = getFormResponse();
  var event = createCalendarEvent(eventObject);
}

function getFormResponse() {
  // Get a form object by opening the form using the
  // form id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var form = FormApp.openById(GLOBAL.formId),
      //Get all responses from the form. 
      //This method returns an array of form responses
      responses = form.getResponses(),
      //find the length of the responses array
      length = responses.length,
      //find the index of the most recent form response
      //since arrays are zero indexed, the last response 
      //is the total number of responses minus one
      lastResponse = responses[length-1],
      //get an array of responses to every question item 
      //within the form for which the respondent provided an answer
      itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses(),
      //create an empty object to store data from the last 
      //form response
      //that will be used to create a calendar event
      eventObject = {};
  //Loop through each item response in the item response array
  for (var i = 0, x = itemResponses.length; i<x; i++) {
    //Get the title of the form item being iterated on
    var thisItem = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle(),
        //get the submitted response to the form item being
        //iterated on
        thisResponse = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
    //based on the form question title, map the response of the 
    //item being iterated on into our eventObject variable
    //use the GLOBAL variable formMap sub object to match 
    //form question titles to property keys in the event object
    switch (thisItem) {
      case GLOBAL.formMap.eventTitle:
        eventObject.title = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.startTime:
        eventObject.startTime = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.endTime:
        eventObject.endTime = thisResponse;
        break; 
      case GLOBAL.formMap.description:
        eventObject.description = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.location:
        eventObject.location = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.email:
        eventObject.email = thisResponse;
        break;
    } 
  }
  return eventObject;
}

function createCalendarEvent(eventObject) {
  //Get a calendar object by opening the calendar using the
  //calendar id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(GLOBAL.calendarId),
      //The title for the event that will be created
      title = eventObject.title,
      //The start time and date of the event that will be created
      startTime = moment(eventObject.startTime).toDate(),
      //The end time and date of the event that will be created
      endTime = moment(eventObject.endTime).toDate();
  
  //an options object containing the description and guest list
  //for the event that will be created
  var eventColour = 1
  var options = {
    description : eventObject.description,
    guests : eventObject.email,
    location: eventObject.location,
  };
  try {
    //create a calendar event with given title, start time,
    //end time, and description and guests stored in an 
    //options argument
    var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, 
                                     endTime, options, eventColour)
      event.setColor = ('5');
      colorID = 1
    } catch (e) {
      //delete the guest property from the options variable, 
      //as an invalid email address with cause this method to 
      //throw an error.
      delete options.guests
      //create the event without including the guest
      var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, 
                                       endTime, options)
      }
  return event;   
}
```

Comment: Is the code you provided yours? Did you put any effort into tying to adapt it to your need? What is the point at which you struggle?

Comment: I did not write this code completely. I got it from an example. 
I need to find a place where to put and a snippet of code which to insert to be able to edit the color of the event created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Have a look at the enum [eventColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color)

- To make you event `BLUE`, you need to assign it the value `9`
- Also, you can not pass the vent color as one of the parameters when creating the event.
- That is

  `var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime,  endTime, options, eventColour)`

  will NOT work
- Instead, pass the color to the event AFTER creating it.

Sample:

```js
var eventColor = 9;
var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime,endTime, options);
event.setColor(eventColor);
```

Comment: Yes, and you could also pass the enum `.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.BLUE)`

Answer (score 0):

[`.setColor()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setcolorcolor) is a method, so you should pass the value into it as a function, rather than assigning with an equals sign.

```
event.setColor(5);
```